# How non numeric keys used in all prime number based algorithms like RSA

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

may be i am asking very dumb question. it is said that rsa (and most other) key pairs are made of prime numbers. but when I generate
key pairs with any key generating tools, it is some text (sometimes base64 / der / ber encoded) and some times unreadable contents. (eg, openSSH keys are base 64 encoded and java keytool generates binary like content). How do they relate these text to a prime number.

I have one more question. What are some algorithms for factoring (find common factors).

Thank you for your time and guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can see the actual prime numbers (in hex) behind the encoding for an RSA key.  There are similar commands for ECDSA and other keys as well.

```
>openssl genrsa -out key.pem
Generating RSA private key, 1024 bit long modulus
..........++++++
........++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)

>more key.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

>openssl rsa -in key.pem -text
Private-Key: (1024 bit)
modulus:
    00:f5:e9:20:1c:4b:e3:05:99:6d:a3:e9:72:8d:d8:
    82:31:bb:82:23:f5:5a:a1:cb:f2:10:0e:0c:c4:b7:
    1f:5c:fb:73:a3:cf:60:2f:16:c6:93:9d:5e:a6:c9:
    bc:96:66:81:97:6c:49:55:96:4f:b9:66:b7:af:c1:
    19:0a:f5:c8:31:24:f2:db:70:fb:ef:05:12:9d:7f:
    3c:db:b6:35:40:6f:cc:ba:e5:f9:9c:79:ac:f6:5e:
    66:e2:d2:7e:47:d6:4b:07:af:c6:28:d2:9f:2f:66:
    aa:6d:b8:64:4a:94:b3:0a:d1:2c:d5:94:4d:ee:35:
    ef:73:d1:14:06:dd:54:11:ed
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    00:b9:ca:cf:da:f1:2e:ed:ed:14:dc:51:a5:9e:2b:
    e5:7a:03:ac:78:d4:88:0c:54:55:67:f1:e5:8d:be:
    b9:70:7b:fe:cb:d6:03:5a:b0:7f:89:c9:cd:58:80:
    74:fe:c1:25:ca:2d:23:5f:09:b8:e4:60:0a:0a:3c:
    ff:59:bb:86:ea:b7:4b:b2:af:19:3f:0f:4c:a8:a1:
    46:2d:61:50:8e:d3:74:82:09:75:ce:16:79:5e:cc:
    97:e3:c6:e4:20:fa:bc:a1:9f:34:ac:b2:76:28:26:
    94:3f:3d:b3:a4:59:fe:28:e8:2f:71:ff:61:f9:c4:
    1e:51:0e:71:93:29:05:f2:f5
prime1:
    00:fe:ea:13:12:ae:6f:15:09:f8:a7:47:0e:f5:4d:
    0b:cb:f1:fc:cd:7c:ce:98:8c:05:35:47:b4:d9:13:
    d7:e3:19:eb:d6:39:66:3b:ed:de:88:6b:12:25:cb:
    08:c7:90:80:f8:33:69:77:96:b0:52:ae:39:ec:2b:
    8e:cc:18:d2:7f
prime2:
    00:f6:f5:3c:05:40:9e:be:65:87:fd:44:da:6b:be:
    a1:b8:46:5b:50:9e:e3:60:1d:94:7c:62:2d:7a:a4:
    e8:3e:9b:0c:69:9e:a6:3a:cb:41:ac:a8:94:df:aa:
    60:08:77:04:ed:26:ce:11:15:45:3f:e0:aa:e2:45:
    f1:34:bd:4d:93
exponent1:
    4d:39:80:59:b2:7a:78:77:32:db:0a:4d:df:c6:5d:
    82:85:66:be:a1:c6:bc:b3:fe:87:eb:97:40:04:20:
    ec:ed:d7:62:68:b5:2e:06:9b:d9:dc:05:fd:69:0a:
    d9:da:4f:17:e2:0b:5b:6d:4d:31:5f:12:b1:17:69:
    05:2f:a7:e5
exponent2:
    00:ca:34:e0:31:38:c9:02:02:a6:47:85:42:06:a8:
    af:47:f0:2b:c2:a6:66:6c:83:ab:d9:f0:95:66:6f:
    72:4e:18:ac:20:2b:2b:d6:c6:28:7f:14:05:d9:e1:
    6a:02:64:59:9f:48:7f:bf:d3:17:c1:86:d6:c4:b1:
    1a:1f:e1:c4:8b
coefficient:
    1a:c0:0a:f3:fa:ce:5b:dd:22:df:c2:35:dc:cb:61:
    0e:43:15:c6:6a:08:e4:c6:b8:6d:d9:7a:de:52:2f:
    d7:b8:2a:e4:da:5f:21:e0:1d:fc:07:e8:bc:7e:29:
    b4:c1:5d:e0:af:c9:08:b4:8c:9e:29:ce:eb:fa:3c:
    e5:aa:f5:5e
```

If your key is in binary DER format, you can get the same output by using this command:

```
openssl rsa -in key.der -inform DER -text
```

Answer (score 3):

The base64 is only a readable representation of the key bits which on their side, are a representation of a large number. Since you can represent integer numbers as bits and sequences of bits can displayed as base64 and vice versa, there is no non numeric key.

For the factorization question: What about [Dixon's algortihm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_algorithm) or the [quadratic sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve)?